# PHP nested foreach to access xml element

Tags: php, xml

I need to access data stored inside an .XML file using PHP

```
XML: 

SimpleXMLElement {#319 ▼
  +"@attributes": array:3 [▶]
  +"suite": SimpleXMLElement {#329 ▼
    +"@attributes": array:3 [▶]
    +"suite": array:4 [▼
      0 => SimpleXMLElement {#332 ▼
        +"@attributes": array:3 [▶]
        +"test": SimpleXMLElement {#347 ▶}
        +"status": SimpleXMLElement {#348 ▶}
      }
      1 => SimpleXMLElement {#333 ▶}
      2 => SimpleXMLElement {#334 ▶}
      3 => SimpleXMLElement {#335 ▶}
    ]
    +"status": SimpleXMLElement {#336 ▶}
  }
  +"statistics": SimpleXMLElement {#330 ▶}
  +"errors": SimpleXMLElement {#331}
}
```

I want access to each of the elements named test which are in suite->suite:

```
foreach($sxml->suite->suite as $name => $f) {
      $feature_name = $f['name'];
        foreach($sxml->suite->suite->test as $name => $t) {
          $test_name = $t['name'];
      
  }}
```

the above code gives me the same test for each feature, rather than the actual test for the feature.

**Current**

Feature 1
Test 1
Feature 2
Test 1

**Expected**

Feature 1
Test 1
Feature 2
Test 2

In the output, I am seeing the same Test for each Feature, rather than each Test for each Feature

Comment: you are assigning the same $test_name variable to all elements of the xml

Comment: and `$sxml->suite->suite->test` is not a valid path (because `$sxml->suite->suite` is an array). You need to use `$f` object.

Comment: @GiacomoM i understand now thank you

Comment: @Syscall that makes sense and led me to the right page of the php docs thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to this question can be found in the offical documentation here:

[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)

and in my example was resolved with:

```
foreach ($sxml->children() as $req) {
        foreach ($req->children() as $feat) {
            foreach ($feat->children() as $test) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXMLElement tag properties behave differently depending on how you access them.

`foreach($root->parent->item as $item)` access the "parent" elements as one element, it will return the first "parent" and ignore siblings. "item" is accessed as iterable (list), so it will return all "item" sibling elements.

To access both as lists you need to nest loops:

```
foreach ($sxml->suite as $parentSuite) {
   foreach ($parentSuite->suite as $suite) {
      foreach ($suite->test as $test) {
         var_dump($test);
      }
   }
}
```

Or use Xpath expressions:

```
foreach ($sxml->xpath('suite/suite/test') as $test) {
    var_dump($test);
}
```